# Is the mtgoxlive depth chart information accurate?

Tags: exchanges, trading, mtgox, live-data

Mt. Gox publishes live data which is available at mtgoxlive.com.  The chart includes the current market price as well as a depth chart of existing bid and ask prices, which I assume is compiled from the order book of each account with the exchange.  However, orders are allowed to be placed on Mt. Gox *without* having available funds in ones account to actually make a trade.  If the depth chart reflects these unfunded orders, they would make the chart steeper than it should be.  Of course, the depth chart may also not reflect trades which people have the funds and intention to make but haven't yet placed in the order book.  In sum, does the mtgoxlive depth chart reflect unfunded orders, and in any event, how useful, accurate, or predictive is it?

Comment: And then there are Dark Pools. I suppose they don't show up in the charts at all.

Comment: Thilo, what do you mean *Dark Pools*? Do you mean bots that only play market price when the prices hit the price they want?

Answer (score 2):

Unfunded orders obviously don't show up in the orderbook. I assume that mtgoxlive is based on the same data provided by the API so it is probably accurate.

If you really want to know, just compare the market depth from mtgoxlive with the ones shown at [bitcoincharts](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/mtgoxUSD_depth.html) and [clarkmoody](http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/).